# Gitlab: What is Merge Train Pipeline which runs after Merge Results pipeline

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have just started with pipeline in gitlab and I have enabled Merge Results Pipeline for my project. What I am observing is that once a Merge Request is raised, there are two things that happen.

1. A Merge Results pipeline runs initially which works on latest changes from source and target branch.
2. Once above pipeline is green and after you click on 'Merge Train' button, another pipeline is started which has info as "Mrge branch Feature xyz with refs/heads/master into refs/merge-requests/::id/train"

I wanted to know what is this second pipeline about?

Answer (score 1):

From gitlab docs:

> When pipelines for merged results are enabled, the pipeline jobs run as if the changes from your source branch have already been merged into the target branch.
>
> However, the target branch may be changing rapidly. When you’re ready to merge, if you haven’t run the pipeline in a while, the target branch may have already changed. Merging now could introduce breaking changes.
>
> Merge trains can prevent this from happening. A merge train is a queued list of merge requests, each waiting to be merged into the target branch.

More details here
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/pipelines_for_merged_results/merge_trains/